# What is the difference between ref and & in Rust pattern matching

Tags: rust

Doing this exercise https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/option/option3.rs I discovered the `ref` keyword and I'm very confused when should I use `&` or `ref` in a pattern matching. In this example, every match outputs the same message, but I couldn't tell their differences:

```rust
struct Point { x: i32, y: i32}

fn main() {
    let y: Option<Point> = Some(Point { x: 100, y: 200 });

    match &y {
        Some(p) => println!("Co-ordinates are {},{} ", p.x, p.y),
        _ => println!("no match"),
    }

    match y {
        Some(ref p) => println!("Co-ordinates are {},{} ", p.x, p.y),
        _ => println!("no match"),
    }

    match &y {
        Some(ref p) => println!("Co-ordinates are {},{} ", p.x, p.y),
        _ => println!("no match"),
    }

    y;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`ref` is older. The fact the matching against a reference gives a reference is a result of the [match ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html) feature.

They are not exactly the same, but generally you can choose. I and many other people prefer the `&` form, although I saw people that do not like match ergonomics and prefer the explicit `ref` always.

There are case where you cannot take a reference and then you're forced to use `ref`. I also prefer to use `ref` in cases like [`Option::as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/option.rs.html#627-630) and [`Option::as_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/option.rs.html#649-652), where with match ergonomics they will have exactly the same code and this is confusing in my opinion, while using `ref` one is just `ref` and the other uses `ref mut`.